# Updating dependency to vite 4 loses some styles in vue 3 app

Tags: vue.js, vite

I have a vue app that works ok in development and builds ok using `"vite": "3.2.4",`. I upgraded the dependencies to `"vite": "4.0.3",` and it still works in development, but there are some missing styles in production. This is in a component that I haven't touched. Here is a little bit of that component:

```
<template>
  <div :class="`inline-svg ${state}`" :style="divStyle" v-html="icon"></div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
.inline-svg.h22 svg {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
}
</style>
```

Notice that the styles are NOT scoped. Most of the CSS in my app is there. Most of the CSS is scoped. There might be other css that are missing but this is the first obvious one.

The disturbing thing is that it looks different in development than when built. I mostly am looking at the development version so there is a class of bugs I'll never notice.

Comment: Did you fin a solution to this?

Comment: It _looks_ like something's changed with the tree-shaking of _apparently_-unused code, leading to that style being stripped.

Comment: I removed `state` from the class and put all the variable styles in `divStyle`. That's a computed value.